# How to find out MAC adress of Hyper-V VM when VM is shut down?

Tags: hyper-v, mac-address

i ran out of luck on this one...

I gave all Hyper-VMs a static mac adress and Msvm_SyntheticEthernetPort returns the mac adress if machine is up but not if its shut down.

if i start the hyper v manager click on a vm and got to the network tab the mac adress is shown so it has to be somewhere accessible?

can anyone give me a hint on how to get it from c#?

thanks to anyone who helps me out!

Answer (score 0):

how about using powershell to get to that?

works like a charm

thanks anyways!
stackoverflow helped me out many many times without even asking!